# loop through list in c#

Tags: c#, list, loops

I wrote a few code line in c# to iterate through a list, but i print in the textbox only the last one. the code that i wrote:

```
//For instantiation
Account account = new Account(0,"","", 0); 

//A list for class Account
List<Account> listAccount = new List<Account>();

//Button for adding new Customer
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        account.CustomerID = int.Parse(customerIdTxt.Text);
        account.CustomerFullName = customerNameTxt.Text;
        account.CustomerAddress = customerAddrTxt.Text;
        listAccount.Add(account);

    }

    //For printing the Customer's detailes in textbox
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string showCustDetailes = "";
        for(int i=0;i<listAccount.Count;i++)
        {
            showCustDetailes+=
                "Customer ID        : " + listAccount[i].CustomerID + Environment.NewLine +
                "Customer Name      : " + listAccount[i].CustomerFullName + Environment.NewLine +
                "Customer Address   : " + listAccount[i].CustomerAddress + Environment.NewLine +
            "---------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        viewDetailesTxt.Text = showCustDetailes;
    }
```

can anyone help me how can i print the whole customers list

Comment: When you say "The last one" do you mean only the "Customer Address" line, or do you mean only one complete ID, Name and Address line?

Comment: Also make sure that your `TextBox` is a multi-line textbox otherwise it will only support a single line.

Comment: You're only using one `Account` instance.

Comment: Ouch, use StringBuilder not string +=

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing wrong with the code that loops over the list (apart from not using `foreach()`). If you really only see one account, the problem is in displaying: make your textbox bigger or give it scrollbars.

Also, you're editing the same instance of `account` every time, so you're filling your list with multiple references to the same account. You must use `new Account` to instantiate a new one for every "button 1" click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Account account = new Account(0,"","", 0); 
    // ...
    listAccount.Add(account);
}
```

Comment: Actualy the code that should be written is that: "Accoount account" on the top of class, and then in one of the relevent function to instantiate  by the code:" account=new Account(0,"","",0) ".

Comment: No, you don't need that. If you don't use the account elsewhere, it's better to give it a scope as small as possible: in the `button1_Click` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Account> listAccount = new List<Account>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var account = new Account {
        CustomerID = int.Parse(customerIdTxt.Text),
        CustomerFullName = customerNameTxt.Text,
        CustomerAddress = customerAddrTxt.Text
    };
    listAccount.Add(account);
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var account in listAccount)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("Customer ID: {0}\nCustomer Name: {1}\nCustomer Address: {2}\n\n", account.CustomerID, account.CustomerFullName, account.CustomerAddress);
    }
    viewDetailesTxt.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```